# (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions php

Tags: php, facebook

Hey guys i have a simple facebook app which uploads a photo to the users timeline.
I already have the publish_actions approved.

How ever when i try to post the photo it returns

> (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions

Here is my source code

```
try {
    // message must come from the user-end
    $data = ['source' => $fb->fileToUpload($generaratedImage), 'message' => 'Support your school team add support banner to your profile picture using'];
    $request = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data);
    $response = $request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

But when i test it with the Open graph test user it works fine..

What am i missing here ?

I recently found when user log in to my app it say

> This does not let the app post to Facebook.

how to fix this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying with an app admin? did you debug your access token? do you get asked for the publish permission when you authorize the app?

Comment: @luschn yes i added the publish permission to the app, I dont understand debug access token ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: What do i have to after debug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I already have the publish_actions approved.

Approved means Facebook allows you to ask normal users for that permission; it does **of course not** mean, that users have granted that permission to your app automatically.

You still need to **ask** the user for the permission, by sending them through the login flow.

Comment: I also have the publish_actions approved by facebook

Comment: It is not about approval – you need to _ask the user_ for the permission.

Comment: how do i do that ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking